# How to accept name and number inputs and add them to the document/webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I've made a document in Word that I'd like people to add their names to, as well as their number of years experience teaching. I've saved it as a web page and posted it here:

http://epicforum.net/TS

...but the operative part is really just this:

http://epicforum.net/TSTest

It's similar to a petition, in that names are appended to the bottom of the document, but it needs more functionality than that, because I want to take the sum of the Years Experience fields and insert that sum in the document itself (i.e. "We, the undersigned, who represent "XXX" years of experience..." etc.). Once people hit the "Add my name as a signatory" button, it takes their name and Years Experience and inputs them in the next available empty row, then adds the next person's info on the next line, etc. Once they hit "Submit", the info is not editable. I don't need high security - nobody will care enough about this document to do anything malicious - but I want to avoid a user error like deleting someone's name who previously signed.

I found and edited HTML that would create the two fields to get input:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
Add my name as a signatory:<br>
<input type="text" name="FLName" value="Name">
<br>
Years Experience:<br>
<input type="number" name="YrsExp" value="Years Experience">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

...but I don't know how to take the input fields and fill the empty lines in the doc with it, nor do I know how to limit the number input to positive number choices, and summing the total YrsExp in the doc isn't something that any posts I could find have addressed. Making it prettier (tabbing the input fields over to align with the text) is, I assume, pretty straightforward(?).

I'd prefer to have it be a separate popup window that takes the input, and found this code that supposedly did that:

```
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
    var el=document.getElementById('button');
    el.onclick=function(){
        var my_text=prompt('Enter text here');
        if(my_text) alert(my_text); // for example I've made an alert
    }
}
</script>
```

...but that didn't create a popup window, and I'm not sure how to pass the input into the doc.

I don't know how to ask this so it's not a "code this for me" question, since the situation is pretty specific.

Where would I look to figure out how to do any of this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using word to create a webpage .This is because word is sometimes pretty simple only for static pages.This means no stunning effects,no responsive design but mainly there is no interactivity(popups forms etc.)
the code for the alert should be:

```
<script>

    window.onload=function()
    {
        var el=document.getElementById('button');
        el.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter text here');
            if(my_text) {alert(my_text); // for example I've made an alert
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Now if you want to have a form that the user will enter something you can do it like this:
html

```
<input type="text" id="years">
<button onclick="experience()">Alert</button>
javascript
<script>

function experience(){
var user_input=document.getElementById('years');
alert("You have "+user_input.value+" years of experience");
}

</script>
```

Also.If you want to save each submitted value you will need a server side language such as PHP.Also the submitted values can't be saved in the original doc file.So you had better create a new .php file or .html file from the beginning.Here is a good site I found about php and forms submission 
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. A few things: 1) Although the button got added, it wasn't a popup. 2) None of the entered text showed up on the page. 3) I want to keep adding the names to the doc - is that even possible? In other words, one user enters their name, it gets added to the bottom of the doc, then the next person who loads the page sees that name when they read it, then add their name, then the third person sees two names at the bottom, etc. 4) If I should be doing it in something other than Word, then what should I be using?

Comment: Definite progress: thanks!  Now if I could just figure out where the FLName field came from or goes, maybe I''d have a handle on it. It can't find the file: "/action_page.php" or the variable/field: "/action_page.php?FLName=David+Low&YrsExp=14"    Should I be reading up on PHP?

Comment: That's the weird part: I don't know where the reference to FLName or YrsExp came from, since I didn't write any form code! Weird....In any case, that PHP website is awesome: thanks!